# Hide parent, but show child div with css

Tags: css

The question is simple, here is the example that is not working:

```
<style>
    .parent {display: none;}
    .child_2 {display: block;}
</style>

<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "child_1">...</div>
    <div class = "child_2">...</div>
    <div class = "child_3">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, but hidden visibility takes up resources?, because the main problem is that the page is loading slowly due to lots of bullshit stuff, and I`m using firefox css insertion plugin to hide everything else, but the content.

Comment: Looks as though your question is a different one from that linked to in the closed message - that is, you don't just want to hide stuff once loaded, using CSS, you actually want to stop it loading. If you rephrase the question to make that clear and also add other tags as it's probably not a pure CSS issue (I think some browsers load stuff even if display is none for example) then maybe you'll get an answer that fits your problem better.